# concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor swallowing exceptions (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7-x64, python-multithreading, cpython

I'm trying to use `ThreadPoolExecutor` in Python 3.6 on Windows 7 and it seems that the exceptions are silently ignored or stop program execution. Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from time import sleep

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

EXECUTOR = ThreadPoolExecutor(2)


def run_jobs():
    EXECUTOR.submit(some_long_task1)
    EXECUTOR.submit(some_long_task2, 'hello', 123)
    return 'Two jobs was launched in background!'


def some_long_task1():
    print("Task #1 started!")
    for i in range(10000000):
        j = i + 1
    1/0
    print("Task #1 is done!")


def some_long_task2(arg1, arg2):
    print("Task #2 started with args: %s %s!" % (arg1, arg2))
    for i in range(10000000):
        j = i + 1
    print("Task #2 is done!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_jobs()
    while True:
        sleep(1)
```

The output:

```
Task #1 started!
Task #2 started with args: hello 123!
Task #2 is done!
```

It's hanging there until I kill it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

However, when I remove `1/0` from `some_long_task1`, Task #1 completes without problem:

```
Task #1 started!
Task #2 started with args: hello 123!
Task #1 is done!
Task #2 is done!
```

I need to capture the exceptions raised in functions running in `ThreadPoolExecutor` *somehow*.

Python 3.6 (Minconda), Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`ThreadPoolExecutor.submit`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) returns a [*future* object](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) that represents the result of the computation, once it's available. In order to not ignore the exceptions raised by the job, you need to actually access this result. First, you can change `run_job` to return the created futures:

```
def run_jobs():
    fut1 = EXECUTOR.submit(some_long_task1)
    fut2 = EXECUTOR.submit(some_long_task2, 'hello', 123)
    return fut1, fut2
```

Then, have the top-level code [wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait) for the futures to complete, and access their results:

```
import concurrent.futures

if __name__ == '__main__':
    futures = run_jobs()
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
    for fut in futures:
        print(fut.result())
```

Calling `result()` on a future whose execution raised an exception will propagate the exception to the caller. In this case the `ZeroDivisionError` will get raised at top-level.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the exceptions with a [`try`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) statement. This is how your `some_long_task1` method could look like:

```py
def some_long_task1():
    print("Task #1 started!")
    try:
        for i in range(10000000):
            j = i + 1
        1/0
    except Exception as exc:
        print('some_long_task1 generated an exception: {}'.format(exc))
    print("Task #1 is done!")
```

Output when the method is used within your script:

```
Task #1 started!
Task #2 started with args: hello 123!
some_long_task1 generated an exception: integer division or modulo by zero
Task #1 is done!
Task #2 is done!
(the last while loop running...)
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question since the question is targeted at catching exception of a subthread and from the nature of the Q description it does not seem like understanding try:  catch: is the problem here, since the OP is asking about catching exceptions specifically already.

Answer (score 1):

As previous answers indicated, there are two ways to catch the exceptions for the `ThreadPoolExecutor` - check the exception in the `future` or log them. It all depends on what one wants to deal with the potential exceptions. In general, my rule of thumb includes:

1. If I *only* want to record the error, including the trace stack. [`log.exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) is a better choice. It needs to add extra logic to record the same amount of information via `future.exception()`.
2. If the code needs to handle different exceptions differently in the main thread. Checking the status of of `future` is the way to go. Also, you might find the function [as_completed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed) is also useful in this circumstance.